# jQuery Slidedown sub menu

Tags: jquery, slide, submenu

i have an html menu,and i want the submenu will be slidedown one by one,

exmaple:
 http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/3armym6y/

but when i add menu level,it's not work again,

```
<div id="nav">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="menus">
        <a href="#">Hover Here</a>
        <ul class="nav-child">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/s3yfyv7k/

As always, your assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

check this fiddle is this you wanted???

http://jsfiddle.net/s3yfyv7k/2/

```
var slide = function(who)
{
    who.slideDown('slow', function(){
       var next = $(this).next('li');
       if (next)
           slide(next);
    });
}

$(".menu1 > a").hover( function() {
    slide($('.nav-child li:first'));
} )
```

Missing target selector

```
slide($('.nav-child li:first'));
```